# MyEclipse - The container 'Struts 1.1 Libraries' references non existing library

Tags: myeclipse

Some time my project in MyEclipse show me the following error on compilation. Sometime by restarting MyEclipse the error message disappear.
Can you please tell me why this error occurs ?

**Error message :**

```
The container 'Struts 1.1 Libraries' references non existing library 'C:\MyEclipse\.......\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\16\1\.cp\data\1.1\lib\commons-beanutils.jar'    ROMO_ETD        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using an old unsupported release of MyEclipse, so one option would be to upgrade to the latest release. Another would be to run MyEclipse with the -clean argument, once. The argument is mentioned here (for the eclipse Juno release, but it's similar for earlier releases): http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm?cp=0_3_0

Basically, the argument is added to the command line or to the top of the myeclipse.ini file, in the folder containing the myeclipse.exe file. The argument can be removed after the first launch, as it slows down the launch.